# mutually exclusive buttons in itemscontrol

Tags: wpf

I have buttons as items of an itemscontrol. It is possible to check the button so that once it is click it will show highlighted until it is clicked again(with an ischecked property). My problem is I need to make this button checking mutually exclusive? At any point I want only one button to be visible as highlighted. I am using itemscontrol because I can wrap the buttons so that it will fill up horizontally till the allocated width and will continue to next line.

the XAML below

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=NewItemsList,ElementName=newitemcontrol}">              
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>                       
                  <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >                       
                         </WrapPanel>
                  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>             
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                            <dc:ButtonDropDown Name="SubItems" Width="120" 
                  Height="120"    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Children, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" Header="{Binding Path=DataContext.DisplayName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"  Command="{Binding Path=ChangeSubItem, ElementName=newitemcontrol}" CommandParameter="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"        ImageSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.ImageUri, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" ImagePosition="Top"           IsCheckable="True" >                           


                            </dc:ButtonDropDown>
                    </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: You can do this with a RadioButton using the GroupName property. I don't know about dc:ButtonDropDown

Comment: also, you may want to use a `Panel` (instead of `ItemsControl`) if the items are static elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you your responses. I need to use dropdownbutton inside a container(I know about radiobutton). The way that I solved this is using listbox instead of itemscontrol. The listbox should be single select,  and bind the dropdownbutton ischecked property to its listboxitem's isselected property.